# Deconvolution of sum results in negative numbers

Tags: distributions, random-variable, fourier-transform, convolution

Given $T=G+A$ where $A$ and $G$ are independent random variables, I'd like to estimate the distribution of $G$ given empirical (measured) distributions of $T$ and $A$. Of note: all three random variables are guaranteed to be bounded on $[0,\infty]$ (unlike the more studied case where $A$ would be a zero mean gaussian).

I understand this is a deconvolution, and I've tried two different deconvolutions with little success. Before deconvolving, most references recommend converting the empirical densities (in this case, $T$ and $A$) into smoother forms using kernel density estimation. I'll call these $P_T$ (black) and $P_A$ (red) respectively.

Then I've tried two deconvolution approaches.

(1) Computing $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\mathcal{F}(P_T)/\mathcal{F}(P_A))$ using matlab's fft and ifft functions. (green)

(2) Computing the deconvolution matrix for $A$ and using a truncated SVD method to solve for $P_G$. (blue)

[image: Deconvolution]

Almost certainly the general shape of both solutions is correct, except.. (1) both oscillate significantly, whereas the correct $P_G$ will not, and (2) both deconvolutions give me negative numbers. Seems like there should be a way to enforce that $G$ is positive but I'm not sure how. Thoughts?